# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' error

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm using an xml to get data to my database, 4 tables works fine but suddenly an error appear and i have no clue how to solve it:

```
tables = soup.find_all('tabela_specjalnosci')

    # for each tabela_specjalnosci looks like there is 2 nested corresponding   tags
    tags = ['id', 'nazwa']
    # initialize empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # iterate over each tabela_specjalnosci and extract each tag and append to pandas dataframe
    for table in tables:
        all = map(lambda x: table.find(x).text, tags) # everything fine
        df = df.append([all], ignore_index=True)
    # insert tags as columns
    df.columns = tags
    # add schedule row by row to database
    for row in df.iterrows():
        object = Specjalnosc(row[1])
        db.session.add(object)
        db.session.commit()
```

that code above works fine but next one suddenly not

```
tables = soup.find_all('tabela_studia')

    # for each tabela_studia looks like there is 2 nested corresponding   tags
    tags = ['id', 'nazwa']
    # initialize empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # iterate over each tabela_studia and extract each tag and append to pandas dataframe
    for table in tables:
        all = map(lambda x: table.find(x).text, tags) #'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
        df = df.append([all], ignore_index=True)
    # insert tags as columns
    df.columns = tags
    # add schedule row by row to database
    for row in df.iterrows():
        object = Studia(row[1])
        db.session.add(object)
        db.session.commit()
```

An xml that i add looks like this:

```
<tabela_specjalnosci data-aktualizacji="1474562975">
  <ID>0</ID>
  <NAZWA><ogólna></NAZWA>
</tabela_specjalnosci>
```

and second one:

```
<tabela_studia data-aktualizacji="1474563008">
  <ID>1</ID>
  <NAZWA>stac. magisterskie jednolite</NAZWA>
</tabela_studia>
```

any suggestion what is wrong here?

Comment: `table.find(x)` can return `None`. Specially when your XML file contains a single tag like `<ogólna>` ... what do you mean by "suddenly not"? It works with the first one and not with the second one, or the other way round?

Comment: Yes, the code works fine with the tabela_specjalnosci and with tabela_studia suddenly not.

Comment: Case closed, the problem was my typo. I guess it's time for some sleep